# MessageBox: Output multiple strings

Tags: c++, windows, forms, messagebox

This is a Windows Form program written in c++.
The objective of this, is getting a word, written by the user in the TextBox called **tbInputSrc**, which is used to search in a code in a file.
The file I opened in this program, contains this:

```
1111 aaaa aaaa 1
2222 bbbb bbbb 3
3333 cccc cccc 5
4444 dddd dddd 7
5555 eeee eeee 7
```

The numbers are the code (codice), the first "word" is the name (nome), the second "word" is the surname (cognome), and the number is the mark (vote) of the student.
So the objective is, to show, in a TextBox, name and surname of the student trough the code written in the TextBox.

```
ifstream input("output.txt");
string cognome, nome;
string text;
int codice, voto;
int tr;

tr = 0;

while (!tr && input >> codice >> cognome >> nome >> voto) {
    if (this->tbInputSrc->Text == Convert::ToString(codice)) {
        tr = 1;
    }
}

if (!tr) {
    MessageBox::Show("Alunno non trovato", "Risultato ricerca", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
} else {
    MessageBox::Show(/*name and surname of the student*/, "Risultato ricerca", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
}

input.close();
```

I've tried to show the name and surname in different ways:
Using a simple sum of string:

```
if (!tr) {
    MessageBox::Show("Alunno non trovato", "Risultato ricerca", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
} else {
    string phrase = cognome + " " + none;
    MessageBox::Show(phrase, "Risultato ricerca", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
}
```

I've tried using c_str:

```
if (!tr) {
    MessageBox::Show("Alunno non trovato", "Risultato ricerca", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
} else {
    string phrase = cognome + " " + none;
    MessageBox::Show(phrase.c_str(), "Risultato ricerca", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
}
```

All of these, give me the error 
[E0304](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/function-overloading?view=vs-2019)
So I wanted to ask, is there an easy, or better way, to show multiple strings in the MessageBox body?

Comment: I think the reason for your question being quite unclear to me are typos. Typos in themselves are not a problem here on StackOverflow (or I myself would be in trouble), but they are really getting in the way of understanding here. So please review and [edit] to fix.

Comment: "I've tried summing strings into another", "I've tried using c_str", "I've tried using marshal"  How? Show that please, ideally as a [mre]. Also please show in each case the result you got and additionally the result you try for in contrast.

Comment: I'll edit the post again with additional code and better grammar

Comment: Do you intentionally mix C++ and C++.NET?

Comment: I did, unintentionally. I'm still learning this type of conventions from C++ to C++.NET and viceversa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `MessageBox::Show` is C++.NET, so its first arguments are of type `System::String^` (managed pointer to `System::String`) and not `std::string` (nor `const char *`). You need to convert your string to that type somehow. Try passing `gcnew String(phrase.c_str())`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8 for details.

Comment: It works! Kinda weird, since I once tried to convert the string with gcnew String. Thanks!

Comment: Probably System::String can’t be constructed from C++ std::string. But phrase.c_str() returns a plain old C string, i.e. a const char array with terminating NUL byte (beware of embedded NULs, std::string allows them but conversion via a C string will truncate at first embedded NUL, if any).